# Aquamacs - reloading buffers from previous session

Tags: aquamacs

In Aquamacs, how I can configure it (e.g., in the init file) so that during start up, it automatically reloads all unclosed buffers from the last time I quit the program?

Answer (score 1):

Use [desktop-save-mode](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Saving-Emacs-Sessions.html). Just put:

(desktop-save-mode 1)

in your .emacs file.